# How can i use 'Q' promise in the nodejs+typescript?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am new in q library. And I have not much experience in nodejs+typescript.

```
   private myfunc(licencenum){
          var Totalunreadcount = require('../models/totalunreadcount');
          var Readchat = require('../models/readchat');
          Readchat.find({licencenum:licencenum},function(err, readchats){
                Totalunreadcount.update({licencenum:licencenum}, { $set: {totalcount:3, unreadcount:4}} ,{upsert:true},function(err){
                     console.log('update success');
                });

          });
   }

   private runmyfunc()
   {
        var q = require('q');
        var mypromise = this.myfunc('1235837').then(){
              console.log('call finished');
        }
   }
```

please tell me how can i run "runmyfunc" successfully.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe do some reading on promises first? I'm sure it would clear a lot of things.

Comment: thanks for reply.  I read but can not understand alone.
Please give me some link or advice. Thanks again.

Comment: SO isn't really a recommendation website but this website explains things very well, and it's based on node https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: I understood about promise from this link. It's clear.   Thanks.

Comment: You can call (run) `rummyfunc` by saying `object.rummyfunc()`. But things are not going to go very well. It will fail to find a `then` on the return value from `myfunc`, since `myfunc` doesn't return anything. It seems that `Readchat.find` is a callback-style interface which would need to be converted into a promise somehow.

Comment: I really faced to this problem. Thanks for your advice, torazaburo.